# Is this a correct proof of injectivity of right inverse function by contraposition?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I'm trying to prove the injectivity of $f: X \to Y$ in $g \circ f = id_X$ (with $g : Y \to X$). This is what I came up with and I'd appreciate someone pointing out any mistakes.

1 $$x \neq x' \implies id_X(x) \neq id_X(x')$$
2 $$\implies (g \circ f) (x) \neq (g \circ f )(x')$$
3 $$\implies g(f(x)) \neq g(f(x'))$$
4 $$\implies f(x) \neq f(x')$$

The surjectivity of $g$ permits the implication in (4), right? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Implication (4) holds because $g$ is a function: if $a=b$, then $g(a)=g(b)$; what you have is the contrapositive, which is logically equivalent. You are not using that $g$ is surjective here.

Comment: And, yes, this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

A direct proof.
Assume $f(a) = f(b)$.
Thus $a = gf(a) = gf(b) = b$.